# Dynamically generating a form in javascript - But the value of the previous fields is lost with each new field added

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html (thymeleaf) page that uses javascript to dynamically add fields to a form. Different buttons add fields with different default values. The problem is, whenever a field is added, it sets all the previous field's value to the new field's value. See the code snippet to make the problem clear.

```js
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
 clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}



/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
    
var count =0;    
function addFields(type){
 
 count = count + 1;
 
   
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=0;i<count;i++){
     container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Type"));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = type;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Timestamp "));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = document.getElementById("time").textContent;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Details(optional)"));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Match</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>

    
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Match of ' + ${part1} + ' and ' + ${part2}"/>
<p id="demo"></p>

<table>

 <tr>
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part1}"/>
  </th>
  <th>
   <h1 id="time"><time >00:00:00</time></h1>
   <button id="start">start</button>
   <button id="stop">stop</button>
   <button id="clear">clear</button>
  </th>   
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part2}"/>
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')" >Ippon!</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')">Ippon!</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')" >Wazari</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')">Wazari</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')" >Shido</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')">Shido</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>  
<br/>


    <div id="container"></div>
    
    


</body>

 

</html>
```

I understand that every time the addField method is run it generates everything from scratch losing the previous values. However I am really struggling to come up with the logic for a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily using `while` and `for` loops and the variable `count`.

With `while` you are deleting all the previously created elements.

And again creating the `n(count)` -> `number of times you clicked any of the buttons` elements with the `for` loop.

Just remove them.

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
 clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}



/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
    
var count =0;    
function addFields(type){
 
 /*count = count + 1;*/
 
   
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    /*while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }*/
    /*for (i=0;i<count;i++){*/
     container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Type"));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = type;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Timestamp "));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = document.getElementById("time").textContent;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Details(optional)"));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    /*}*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Match</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>

    
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Match of ' + ${part1} + ' and ' + ${part2}"/>
<p id="demo"></p>

<table>

 <tr>
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part1}"/>
  </th>
  <th>
   <h1 id="time"><time >00:00:00</time></h1>
   <button id="start">start</button>
   <button id="stop">stop</button>
   <button id="clear">clear</button>
  </th>   
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part2}"/>
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')" >Ippon!</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')">Ippon!</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')" >Wazari</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')">Wazari</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')" >Shido</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')">Shido</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>  
<br/>


    <div id="container"></div>
    
    


</body>

 

</html>
```